# ReactJS. Images disappear on window resize

Tags: javascript, reactjs, resize

Here's the files:

**script.jsx:** (the main script)

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    ReactDom.render(
        <Body>
            <Collage />
        </Body>,
        document.querySelector('#body'),
    );
});
```

**body.jsx:**

```js
const Body = function (props) {
    return (
        <>
            {props.children}
        </>
    );
};

export default Body;
```

**collage.jsx:**

```js
export default class Collage extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            images: [
                { src: '/home/photos/vertical/1' },
                { src: '/home/photos/vertical/0' },
            ],
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="collage">
                {this.state.images.map(image => <Image src={image.src} key={Math.random()} />)}
            </div>
        );
    }
```

**image.jsx:**

```js
const Image = ({ src, alt }) => (
    <img className="collage__img"
         alt={alt}
         src={`${src}.jpg`}
         onTransitionEnd={evt => evt.target.remove()} />
);

Image.propTypes = {
    src: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    alt: PropTypes.string,
};

Image.defaultProps = {
    alt: '',
};

export default Image;
```

So, **script.jsx** should render `Body` and `Collage` components. All that `Body` does is just returns it's children. The `Collage` consists of one `div` with a list of `Image`. And images' data stored in `Collage` state. The `Image` is just an `img`.

When the page is loaded everything works fine. But when the I'm resizing the window, the images are disappearing for some reason.

If you want to see, how the images are disapearing, there's a [video](https://youtu.be/_NAP2ObBPcE).

This behaviour seems to be broken. I think this may be a bug. But I want to someone who understands React say so. If it's not, please, describe it.

---

The code above may looks strange, but this is just a minimal reproducible example. I can also share the full code. Here's the [repository](https://github.com/Yoskutik/MyInspire-ph.ru-React)

Comment: I think it should have something to do with the `onTransitionEnd={evt => evt.target.remove()}`, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images indeed disappear because they are removed in `onTransitionEnd={evt => evt.target.remove()}`, as [@tanmay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4315380/tanmay) says.
As I understand it is intentional and supposed to happen on mobile screen-sizes on opacity transition [here](https://github.com/Yoskutik/MyInspire-ph.ru-React/blob/master/home/elements/collage/collage.jsx#L44-L45)

Now, why would that happen on resize. Because there's another transition, of `font-size`, that happens on `html` element [here](https://github.com/Yoskutik/MyInspire-ph.ru-React/blob/18f9c3c6762eddc33cd590e7c368534e7444875e/assets/styles/Base.scss#L79-L96). And `font-size` is an inherited property so it changes for images and every element under `html`.

What to do to avoid it but leave removalon transition in place.
Three ways:

1. Check for property name `onTransitionEnd={evt => evt.propertyName === 'opacity' && evt.target.remove()}`
2. Explicitly set what properties to transition with `.collage__img {transition-property: opacity;}`
3. Make `font-size`  not `inherit` with `.collage__img {font-size: initial;}`

I'd go with option 2. Certainly not option 3, as that only accounts for `font-size` transition and leaves `onTransitionEnd` to trigger on any other transition that may be added in the future.

Comment: Also, in general it's not a good idea to remove elements with DOM API if you are already using React. The right way would be to change `state.images` array